# One Button but multiple function,but control function using buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I assigned multiple(4) function for onClick, but i want to use only three functions sometimes and other set of three functions sometimes amongst 4 functions. so i want to control this change using two different buttons.so kindly help me with full HTML code,because i am very new to Html..Thanks in advance!!

```
<button type="button" onclick="pushButton(0);onClick();pushButton1(0);pushButton2(0);" value="Call2Functions">
```

Comment: <button type="button" onclick="pushButton(0);onClick();pushButton1(0);pushButton2(0);" value="Call2Functions">

Comment: Please elaborate more on your question and provide enough codes to show what you have done so far and also so that we can reproduce the scenario.

Comment: ,I created separate function but I want to use single button to execute all function sometimes only three and other time some other set of functions but with same button

Comment: You are asking other users to write code for you, I think you missunderstood the purpose of stackoverflow. You should post your own solution, thoroughly explain what's wrong and what you are attempring to do and people will help you with your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear. You have 4 functions and you want buttons to control 3 of them at a time. So it's pretty simple. Call the needed 3 functions on first button click and again call the other 3 on the second button click. But if you want only 1 button to control this behaviour you can do something like this in javascript:

```
button.onclick = function(){
    if(condition 1){
        // call three functions
    }
    else {
        // call other 3
    }
}
```